# res.pipe renders a loading page rather than the actual page, which is not an intended behavior for me

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am trying to render any webpage on my server using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

```
 `req.pipe(request(imageUrl).pipe(res);`
```

Actual Response: [Rendered webpage of loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQMqD.png)
Expected Response: The actual webpage but not the loading screen. This mosly happens on React based services

I have tried :

```
     if (targetUrl.startsWith('https://')) {
        // proxy random image from picsum website
        const imageUrl = targetUrl;
        req.pipe(request({ url: imageUrl, form: req.body })).pipe(res);
      }
```

Comment: I changed my approach of using request library, with axios.get(url) 
Still some pages do not load properly. Closing this as i am no more using this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
    // Make a request to the website and pipe the response to the response of our endpoint
  request
    .defaults("127.0.0.1:8080")
    .get(url)
    .on("error", (err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send("Error occurred while proxying the website.");
    })
    .on("response", (response, body) => {
      // Remove X-Frame-Options header to allow embedding in iframe
      delete response.headers["x-frame-options"];
      console.log(response);
    })
    .pipe(res);
```

This is a working solution

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).